# AngularJS SelectedRow Post

Tags: php, angularjs, post

Where can I make mistakes? I need to click button submitedRows inserted to database.

```
$http.post("http://localhost/insert.php",{'isbn':$scope.submitedRows[0].isbn},{headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}}).success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
     console.log("data inserted successfully");
 });
```

PHP code I can connect to db:

```
   $db = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);
   $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
   $isbn = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['isbn']);
   if(! $db )
   {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO deneme (isbn) VALUES ('".$isbn."');";
if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($db);
}
```

Comment: try removing the 3rd (config) argument to $http.post

Comment: not work. and input.php isbn is undefined index ?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  If you console.log your error callback, is there anything in it?

Comment: I solved the problem